# How can I do a nested MySQL Query in PHP with this database I created?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I have created a website / backend database which we are going to be using for a quiz that we put on in our region.  We call it Battle of the Books.  The Database has three tables.  Battles, Rounds, and Questions.  In the Battle table I have a primary key that I refer to the battle with (id).  A battle can have many rounds, so in the round table, each round has it's own primary key (id) and also a column that I call battle_id that i use to refer back to the main battle.  In the round table, there is a column that I call round_questions.  It has a list of questions that will be asked in that round.  I am using a comma separated list of numbers here that I explode out into an array when I am working with it in PHP.  What I need to do now that I have all the parts working where people can create battles, rounds, questions, and associate them all together is to pull it all together in one page so I can display the battle to the moderator.

The SQL would be something like,  SELECT ALL INFO FROM THE ROUNDS AND BATTLE TABLES THAT HAVE A BATTLE_ID of 'whatever the battle is they are looking at" and then i need to iterate through the questions in each round plus pull out some of the other columns in the battle table and round table that have notes.  Can someone help me figure out what the best way would be to get all that information?

Comment: Couple notes to help get you to your answer... 1 .  MySQL, or SQL-Server?  It can't be both.   2.  Are you familiar with "fiddle"  it is a quick and easy way to share DB Scenarios like this for best explanation.  Which leads me to 3.  Can you post examples of you tables.   All that being said your description is sound, but your question is BROAD.    It will be hard to give you a definitive answer, but your scenario is definitely easily accomplished.    Final note...  Comma delimited "round_Questions" = Bad Idea.  This should be another child table. just like Rounds is of Battles

Comment: I meant http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Here is an example sqlfiddle based roughly off what you said.   This will be a good place to start.    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92bbf4

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like that. Receive my answer as guidance but not as solution. :) Be careful to uppercase or lowercase of the names of tables or fields. It is usually case sensitive.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM ROUNDS t1, BATTLE t2 WHERE t1.BATTLE_ID = t2.BATTLE_ID
```